# onPause fires directly when called onActivityResult

Tags: android, onpause

I am using `onActivityResult()` and `onPause()` methods in one activity.
Now the problem is that whenever `onActivityResult()` fires, it calls `onPause()` in the end and so application gets close.
How to prevent this problem ?
Code :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: and where is code sir? put your code here

Comment: why do you call finish() inside onPause=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the boolean variable and activate it onActivityForResult method.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
if(!isActivate)
    finish();
}
```

Comment: @JeetenParmar what worked and how worked.. can you explain.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are calling `finish();` on `onPause()`. Remove that.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    //finish();
}
```

When you call `finish()` caller Activity will be destroyed, so when called Activity finishes the task your app is closing, because there is no Activity (any more) which will handle the result.

***So simply remove*** `finish()`

Comment: sorry, i am new to android development. after uploading image, I am going on new activity. So If anyone click on back button of mobile device then will it close the app ???

Comment: yes. your app will close. BUT Only IF the current Activity is the last in ActivityStack.